# Bind-mounting location on Docker registry results in timeouts

Tags: macos, docker, timeout, docker-registry, mount-point

I’m using Docker on Mac, and I’m having some trouble with bind-mounting a location on a registry server- I was hoping someone here might be able to help.

Thankfully, the issue is pretty simple. Let’s say I want to run a simple, insecure, docker registry. First, I make sure that the appropriate ip:portno is entered into the "insecure registries" list. As per the documentation, I then run `docker run -d --restart=always --name registry -e REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:5000 -p 5000:5000 registry:2`

When I do that, the registry "just works." I can tag an image as `10.0.3.59:5000/imgname`, and push and pull normally.

However, I'd like the registry's data to be located at a specific location on the host system, say, `/mnt/registry`. I go to the docker preferences, make sure that sharing is enabled on the `mnt` folder, and remove old images and containers

Following the documentation again, I run `docker run -d --restart=always --name registry -v storage:/var/lib/registry/ -e REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:5000 -p 5000:5000 registry:2`. However, if I now try to do a `docker push 10.0.3.59:5000/imgname` now, I get the following messages

```
The push refers to a repository [10.0.3.52:5000/cropspokyimage]
74146a4cf164: Retrying in 9 seconds
6c45ce1e774e: Retrying in 9 seconds 
0914c5636fb4: Retrying in 9 seconds
f859b8ada191: Retrying in 9 seconds
b2d02a400fe3: Retrying in 9 seconds
fc0e50be166d: Waiting
a8cfe888247e: Waiting
e745d991dded: Waiting
7b08edaa4533: Waiting
01b4d034aab5: Waiting
d0c686d0df68: Waiting
9deb78b26d56: Waiting
0566c118947e: Waiting
6f9cf951edf5: Waiting
182d2a55830d: Waiting
5a4c2c9a24fc: Preparing
cb11ba605400: Waiting
```

After about a minute or so of waiting, it finally prints the following error and terminates `received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Internal Server Error`

Obviously, this leaves me without some much-desired functionality. Would anyone be able to help me find a solution?

Comment: Did the registry logs say anything?

Comment: @Grimmy I hadn't thought to look there. The logs were complaining that a certain directory didn't exist, I've since enabled it and I *think* it's working now. As a followup, would you know how to give the daemon elevated privileges?

Comment: I deleted all related images and containers to make sure that my success was reproducible. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be- I run into the same timeout behavior described earlier- expect this time, the logs complain that (the daemon?) could not run "mkdir /var/lib/registry/docker"- this is the same error as previously, but the directory actually exists on my machine now. I'm a little confused atm

Comment: `-v storage:/var/lib/registry/` .. might be better to use absolute path on the host as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some issues here. First was that the directory I had mounted for the volume had the wrong permissions, so docker couldn't write to it. A `cmod 777` fixed that.

Using the `docker logs` command to inspect the logs of the registry was crucial.

Inspecting the logs also revealed that the `restrict-useradd` script was erring when the user it was trying to add already existed, so adding an `|| 0` to the return value in the script fixed that. This was an issue with `restrict-groupadd` too